# Is it possible to sort based on a calculated column in MS Access using SQL? Is this an order of solving issue?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The use case is a PC hardware store where you want to have an idea of how much each terabyte of data on a hard drive costs. We'll have pricing history but we only want the most recent cost per TB for each product in this query.

We have two tables, a table that provides info on a product, and a table that provides the long term pricing for that product (one to many). TB is the amount of terabytes on a hard drive. I can make the following work but **only** without the final order by. It appears that the alias "pptb", although it's absolutely present in the output of the query, is not known to the interpreter when you put it in the final Order By. The list absolutely needs to be sorted by the price per terabyte so we know what the best deal is.

I considered doing this with an Inner Join but MS Access SQL doesn't have simple "limit", instead requiring "top" and that pretty much required me to do a subquery in this situation.

```
SELECT p.ProductID, 
       p.Description, 
       p.TB, 
       ((-Int(-(100*currentprice/p.TB)))/100) AS pptb, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Price 
        FROM Price AS unitprice 
        WHERE p.[ProductID] = unitprice.relatedproductid 
        ORDER BY unitprice.dateadded DESC, unitprice.id DESC) AS currentprice 
FROM product AS p 
ORDER BY pptb desc;
```

Any idea, kindhearted dev types? I've looked all over S.O. and can't find anything that's exactly like this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases in Access can only be used in the select output, not in other parts of the query.  One workaround is to subquery your current query, and then use the aliases anywhere you like:

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    Description,
    TB,
    ((-Int(-(100*currentprice / TB))) / 100) AS pptb,
    currentprice
FROM
(
    SELECT
        p.ProductID,
        p.Description,
        p.TB,
        (SELECT TOP 1 Price 
         FROM Price AS unitprice 
         WHERE p.[ProductID] = unitprice.relatedproductid 
         ORDER BY unitprice.dateadded DESC, unitprice.id DESC) AS currentprice
    FROM product AS p
) t
ORDER BY
    ((-Int(-(100*currentprice / TB))) / 100) DESC;
```

Comment: You know, I thought that too but when I try it, it complains about not knowing what currentprice is

Comment: @cente Sorry, I didn't read the full query.  Please check the updated answer.

Comment: SQL Server supports “order by N”, where N is a number referring to the N-th select column. In this case that would be “order by 4 desc”. Does MS Access support this?

Comment: This is absolutely it. I'm wrapping my head around what you did but I think I'm close to figuring it out. Thank you so much, stranger!

Comment: @user2864740 Not according the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/order-by-clause-e8ea47f7-5388-460a-bec8-dcc81792d762), and that wouldn't help anyway, since the OP also is trying to reuse an alias in the select clause.